# Wordpress - Clone plugins (with settings) to new WP install

Tags: wordpress, clone

Is there a way to clone a Wordpress website but keep all the plugin settings etc for a completely new website?

I've turned Wordpress into a cms with the help of some plugins and some of my own tweaks. I want to roll this out as the cms I use for every website I create so therefore don't want to have to install all the plugins each time and adjust their settings.

I don't want to copy the content of the site just the plugins.

It's not as simple as ftp'ing all the files down then up to some new hosting space.

How can I go about cloning the website?

Would wordpress multisite work for this? I know it does sub domains etc but can I use multisite over several different domains?

Comment: "I know it's not quite as simple as copying down then files then copying them up for the new site!" It pretty much is. You'd just need to change the site title and URL in the settings.

Comment: If you have the code in a repository (you should), then you can push the code to the new site using svn export or something similar for git for the files (also tarball or rsync for best practice).  This stuff if pretty standard sandbox management.

Comment: @Horus Hmm I'm wondering of the benefits of running everything from one copy in a repository. On the one hand I'll be able to get all versions of the cms the same but on the other, certain upgrades may break the cms across the board (something that happened recently).

Comment: What I mean is that a database build script and the web application code should be in subversion, mercurial, or git.  Using this and a sandbox manager, you should be able to easily build out copies of the applications to other boxes (even vm's) without too much issue.

Comment: I've made my question a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the process:

1. Ftp down the files from your existing site.
2. Change the wp_config to the new details of the database.
3. Ftp up the files to the new site.
4. Download the database of the old site.
5. Import into the database of the new site. Change the wp_options siteurl to the new site address.
6. Login to the admin and change the site address to the new domain.
7. Update the permalinks.

The site is cloned successfully.

Comment: You're copying the whole database needlessly. All you need is `wp_options` most likely.

Answer (score 1):

A backup of the database, and a copy of the files in the wordpress directories. On the new site, you would need to have changed the URL in the config database, which if you backup the database you could change in the text file you backed up to, before uploading to the new site.

Also http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL suggests you could set a setting and any chances will be auto reflected when you load it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the copy wasn't corrupted?

Please check if the `/home/biologic/public_html/wp-includes/load.php` file is there.

Or maybe the `ABSPATH` above is wrong... if it is, then check if you have this on your `wp-config.php` file:

```
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

if it is there, replace `dirname(__FILE__) . '/'` with the actual absolute path, hardcoding it.